# MeteorServlet does not allow redirect

Tags: java, spring, servlets, atmosphere

I use redirect in the spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getView(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:test");
}
```

When I configure web.xml like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class> 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

redirect works.
But with next configuration -

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.MeteorServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.servlet</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

browser showed only blank page. There are no errors in tomcat's log.